# Adding multiple .random classes to multiple divs without a duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

Trying to add a random class to two classes (.left & .right) but with a rule of the two random divs cannot appear at the same time

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var classes = ['random-1','random-2', 'random-3']; //add as many classes as u want
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length);

$('.left').addClass(classes[randomnumber]);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="left">
  Left
</div>

<div class="right">
  Right
</div>


.left {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.right {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

  .random-1 {
     background: orange;
  }
  .random-2 {
     background: yellow;
  }
  .random-3 {
     background: pink;
  }
  .random-4 {
     background: green;
  }
  .random-5 {
     background: blueviolet;
  }
```

Ideal result would be

```
<div class="left random-1">
  Left
</div>

<div class="right random-4">
  Right
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OOJaqL

Comment: How are you applying the randomness?

Comment: And you need this for two elements only (or for multiples of left/right elements)? If so, the obvious and trivial solution, and rather surprising if you didn't come across that during your research in one form or other, would be to simply shuffle the array, and then take the first two values out of it ...

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError check the codepen

Comment: @pedram _"@OP put that into the question"_ is the correct response ;-)

Comment: @Rob correct this in the first level `$('left')` to `$('.left')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a while loop that iterates until two random and unique classes have been chosen.

```
function getRandomClass() {

    let classes = ['random-1','random-2', 'random-3'];
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length);

    return classes[index];
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    let leftClass = null;
    let rightClass = null;

    while (leftClass == rightClass) {
        leftClass = randomClass();
        rightClass = randomClass();
    }

    $('.left').addClass(leftClass);
    $('.right').addClass(rightClass);
});
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for! Thanks @Callam

Answer (score 0):

Add the `.random-*` class to the left div, only when the right div does not have this class.

```
var rightHasClass = $('.right').hasClass(classes[randomnumber]);    
if( ! rightHasClass){
    $('.left').addClass(classes[randomnumber]);
}

var leftHasClass = $('.left').hasClass(classes[randomnumber]);
if( ! leftHasClass){
    $('.right').addClass(classes[randomnumber]);
}
```